# How to add an item to the JsonRestStore local storage?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using tree with `dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel` as a model and `JsonRestStore` as a store.

It works fine when tree is initialised. After that I want to add another item to the store manually (not from server) to update the tree.

My question is how can I do it without posting the item to server by rest, just to local storage. I used `store.newItem()` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out what fired requests to server. That was `jsonRestStore.save()`, that commits dirty data to server.
After I've removed it from my code, I use the following to add new data to tree:

```
jsonRestStore.fetchItemByIdentity({
    identity: parent.path,
    onItem: function (parent) {
        store_cloud.newItem(child, {
            parent: parent,
            attribute: 'children'
        });
    }
});
```

Here I have a child node and parent one. Also 'children' attribute is used for referencing.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation, you probably wouldn't want to actually use a JsonRestStore. Depending on your use case, you may want to use some other type of dojo store like [Memory](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Memory.html) and on initialization of your Tree, load the data from your server through some other method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have to use `JsonRestStore` to have lazy-loaded, but I also need to find a way to add nodes to the tree loaded by other xhr requests. I don't know a way to use memory with lazy loaded tree nodes.

Comment: This is a tough one that I'm not too sure about then. What I would consider is overriding the newItem function in the StoreModel that backs up the tree (default is ForestStoreModel) and maybe potentially rewriting the onNewItem function. The newItem function should be where the StoreModel for the tree writes to the store so it's in that code where you can stop the POST from occuring.